# How can I clip all the images in a collection of MODIS NDVI in Google Earth Engine and export them separately?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I want to clip all the images in a collection separately and export them. I am new to scripting.

```
//Map.addLayer(table, {color: 'FF0000'} , 'geometry');

var NDVICollection=ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                         .filterDate('2000-01-01','2000-12-31')
                         .filterBounds(table).select('NDVI');

var list = NDVICollection.toList(3);
    for (var i=1;i<4;i++){
         var nam=ee.String('NDVI_img')
                    .cat(ee.String(ee.Number(i)))
                    .getInfo();
var NDVIClipped = NDVICollection.clip(table);

var reprojected = NDVIClipped
    .unitScale(-2000, 10000)
    .reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 500);
//Map.addLayer(reprojected, {min: 0.0, max: 1}, 'Reprojected');
     //print(nam);
     Export.image.toDrive({ 
           image: reprojected,
           description:nam,
           scale: 250,
           maxPixels:1e13
     });
}
```

**I'm getting the error message:**

> NDVICollection.clip() is not a function.

Comment: Do you get an error message when you run your code or what?

Comment: yes, its saying NDVICollection.clip() is not a function.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to use an `ee.Image` function in an `ee.ImageCollection` object. You can map using `.clip()` trough images inside this collection as:

```
// create function to crop with table boundaries
var table_bounds = function(image) {
  // Crop by table extension
  return image.clip(table);
};

var NDVIClipped = NDVICollection.map(table_bounds);
```

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks!